# Flask per-application template folder

Tags: python, templates, web, flask

I implementing simple site with couple of applications (like blog, code, account, etc). I decided to split one python file to apps due to large size. I do not using blueprints or something else except basic functionality of Flask - I'd like to keep it as simple as it possible.
Unfortunately, flask still looking for templates in the

```
/site
|-> main.py
     from flask import Flask

     app = Flask(__name__)
     app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')

     # Import all views
     from errors.views import *  # Errors hasn't its specific prefix
     from blog.views import *
     from account.views import *
     from mysite.views import *

     if __name__ == "__main__":
         app.run(debug=True)
|-> templates
...................
|->blog
  |-> template
    |-> _layout.html
    |-> index.html
    |-> post.html
  |-> __init__.py
     from main import app
     import blog.views
  |-> views
     from blog import app
     from flask import render_template

     @app.route("/blog/", defaults={'post_id': None})
     @app.route("/blog/<int:post_id>")
     def blog_view(post_id):
         if post_id:
             return "Someday beautiful post will be here with id=%s" % post_id
         else:
             return "Someday beautiful blog will be here"

     @app.route("/blog/tags/")
     def tags_view():
         pass
     ..........................
```

Comment: A much as I understand where you're coming from re: keeping it simple I still strongly suggest giving blueprints a try. They're specifically designed for this kind of thing (modularity). Is there another reason you're not using them other than simplicity?

Comment: could you explian how to use blueprints? I just tried to do it with 2 apps - `blog` and `mysite`. Now all templates for top level url (localhost:5000/) are taken from `blog` template folder, not from `mysite/template`.

Comment: I using following blueprint registering:
`app.register_blueprint(mysite.application, url_prefix='/')`
`app.register_blueprint(blog.application, url_prefix='/blog')`

Comment: I'll try and do up a quick demo... While you're waiting gave a read of this: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/blueprints/#templates Does that make sense?

Comment: I saw this page, unfortunately, for my case (with multiple apps, each has its own 'template' folder) it does not works, I checked it already. Actually I found only one rough solution - for application <app> use template directory like `site/<app>/templates/<app>`, but it is very ugly.

Comment: Yeah.. crude it is... Have a look at this: https://github.com/mnbbrown/flask-blog

Could that work?

Comment: Ok, thanks for sample, but it is only for 1 application =) Try to add another (beside `blog`) with the same structure but different content of `index.html`. I suspect one of routes will renders wrong template.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27632/discussion-between-matthew-brown-and-alex-g-p)

Comment: @Alex G.P. - I am facing the same problem. Have you got any solution?

Comment: @virus I decided not to fight agains framework and using approach specified in comment below.

Answer (score 3):

Lets say you have 2 blueprints blog and account. You can divide up your individual apps(blueprints) of blog and account as follows:

```
myproject/
    __init__.py
    templates/
        base.html
        404.html
         blog/
            template.html
            index.html
            post.html
         account/
            index.html
            account1.html
    blog/
        __init__.py
        views.py
    account/
        __init__.py
        views.py
```

In your blog/views.py, you can render templates like:

```
@blog.route('/')
def blog_index():
    return render_template('blog/index.html')

@account.route('/')
def account_index():
    return render_template('account/index.html')
```

..and so on

Comment: It makes sense. But I dislike it. By some reasons I prefer to keep all application-wide resources inside application directory.

Answer (score 2):

Add `template_folder='templates'` to each app Blueprint declaration:

```
account = Blueprint('account', __name__, template_folder='templates')
```

Details: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/blueprints/#templates

Answer (score 0):

more improvement

```
app = Flask(__name__)
current_dir = os.getcwd() # To get the Template folder dynamicly

templates_bp = Blueprint('templates', __name__, template_folder=app.root_path)
```